# How to pick date format in Flutter based on user preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

In US day goes commonly before month e.g. `17/01`. 
When in Europe it is vice versa  `01/17`

On Android I will use `DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder` in order to pick the correct format. How I can do that in Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember where I found this, but I use it and it works perfectly.

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormat.yMMMMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());
var timeFormatter = DateFormat.jms(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());
```

```
Text(dateFormatter.format(value)),
Text(timeFormatter.format(value)),
```

For more informations about date format, check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

You'll probably have to restart the app (main.dart) to see the change, not just hot restart.